# Snoopy module in Puppet returns "Could not find declared class snoopy::install"

Tags: puppet, syslog, snoopy

I am getting an error on the snoopy module. When I run it on my client, I am getting this error:

> "Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER:
>   Puppet::Parser::AST::Resource failed with error ArgumentError: Could not find declared class snoopy::install at /etc/puppet/modules/snoopy/manifests/init.pp:22 on node <hostname>
>   Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
>   Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run"

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?  This is the snoopy module from git with a couple of modifications for our environment.  https://forge.puppet.com/revolutionsystem/snoopy

```
install.pp
    $ cat install.pp
    # snoopy::install
    #
    # A description of what this class does
    #
    # @summary A short summary of the purpose of this class
    #
    # @example
    #   include snoopy::install
    class snoopy::install {
      # Download snoopy installation script
      file { '/tmp/snoopy':
        ensure => directory,
        owner  => 'root',
        group  => 'root',
        mode   => '0755',
      } ->
      exec { 'wget installer':
        command => "/usr/bin/wget http://159.79.213.28/pub/PUPPET/snoopy-    install.sh",
        creates => "/tmp/snoopy/snoopy-install.sh",
        require => [ File['/tmp/snoopy'], ];
      } ->
      # Install Snoopy stable version
      exec { '/tmp/snoopy/snoopy-install.sh stable':
        cwd     => '/tmp/snoopy',
        command => '',
        path    => [ '/bin/bash' ],
        unless  => [ 'test -f /tmp/snoopy/snoopy-install.sh']
        require => [ File['/tmp/snoopy'], File['/tmp/snoopy/snoopy-    install.sh'], ];
      }
    }'


    $ cat init.pp
    # snoopy
    #
    # A description of what this class does
    #
    # @summary A short summary of the purpose of this class
    #
    # @example
    #   include snoopy
    class snoopy (
      $user_name         = $::snoopy::params::username,
      $user_id           = $::snoopy::params::userid,
      $group_id          = $::snoopy::params::groupid,
      $super_id          = $::snoopy::params::superid,
      $terminal          = $::snoopy::params::terminal,
      $current_directory = $::snoopy::params::currentdirectory,
      $process_id        = $::snoopy::params::processid,
      $file_name         = $::snoopy::params::filename,
      $log_file          = $::snoopy::params::logfile,
      $log_path          = $::snoopy::params::logpath,
      $date_time         = $::snoopy::params::datetime
    ) inherits snoopy::params {
      class { 'snoopy::install': }
      class { 'snoopy::configure':
        username         => $user_name,
        userid           => $user_id,
        groupid          => $group_id,
        superid          => $super_id,
        terminal         => $terminal,
        currentdirectory => $current_directory,
        processid        => $process_id,
        filename         => $file_name,
        logfile          => $log_file,
        logpath          => $log_path,
        datetime         => $date_time
      }
    }
```

This can bel closed, it is related to the version of puppet agent we are running.  Module required version >= 4.0.0 and <= 6.0.0.
We are running 3.8.x.

Comment: Is `install.pp` in the same directory as the corresponding `init.pp`?  Is it readable by the Puppet user (which is normally *not* privileged)?

Comment: The provided link is to snoopy and not the snoopy module. Please update the link.